# ajax first input value undefined

Tags: html, ajax

So here is my code,

```
function getProduct(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"./services/getproductlist.php",
                    method: "GET",
                    success: function(res){
                        $("#product-list").html('');
                        var count = 1;
                        console.log(res);
                        res.forEach(function(item){
                            var row = $("<tr></tr>");
                            var col1 = $("<td>" + count + "</td>");
                            var col2 = $("<td>" + item['nama_produk'] + "</td>");
                            var col3 = $("<td>" + item['harga_produk'] + "</td>");
                            var col4 = $("<td><input type='number' name='inp' id='inpqty' required value = '<?php echo 2 ?>'></input></td>");
                            
                            var btn = $('<td scope="col"></td>');
                            var add = $('<a href="#" id="add-btn"><svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="16" style="color: black; margin-left: 10px;"><use xlink:href="#basket"/></svg></a>');
                            var add2 = $('<a href="#" id="inp-btn"><svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="16" style="color: black; margin-left: 10px;"><use xlink:href="#basket"/></svg></a>');

                            add.data('id_produk', item['id_produk']);
                            add2.data('qty', $("#inpqty").val());
                            console.log(item['id_produk']);
                            console.log(item['harga_produk'] * $("#inpqty").val());
                            

                            col1.appendTo(row);
                            col2.appendTo(row);
                            col3.appendTo(row);
                            col4.appendTo(row);
                            add.appendTo(btn);
                            add2.appendTo(btn);
                            btn.appendTo(row);
                            count++;
                            $("#product-list").append(row);
                        });
                        $("#tableImage").DataTable();
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert('fail');
                    }
                });
            }
```

When I tried `console.log($("#inpqty").val())`, the first value always return `undefined` but not the others.

I tried to find the problem but I can't, is there anyone that can help me?

[image: Console log from browser]

Comment: why you are using `value = <?php echo 2 ?>` ? while you can simply add `value='2'`

Answer (score 0):

Inside the for loop:

```
res.forEach(function(item){
    var row = $("<tr></tr>");
    var col1 = $("<td>" + count + "</td>");
    var col2 = $("<td>" + item['nama_produk'] + "</td>");
    var col3 = $("<td>" + item['harga_produk'] + "</td>");
    var col4 = $("<td><input type='number' name='inp' id='inpqty' required value = '<?php echo 2 ?>'></input></td>");

    ...

    add2.data('qty', $("#inpqty").val());
    console.log(item['id_produk']);
    console.log(item['harga_produk'] * $("#inpqty").val());

    ...

    $("#product-list").append(row);
});
```

The first time you look for `inpqty`, the element has not been added to the page body, `product-list`, yet.

That's why it return `NaN`

I'm not sure the value is static or not, but with the info. you provided, you can do this:

```
console.log(item['harga_produk'] * <?php echo 2 ?>);
```

Answer (score 0):

You multiplying `item['harga_product']` with the element doesnt exist in the element.
You see the first time it loop, there’s no `inpqty` inserted to document yet, hence no value and undefined, the solution I think you can try console them below `$("#product-list").append(row);`

OR

when you multiply
`const qtyValue = isNaN(parseInt($("#inputqty").val())) ? 0 : $("#inputqty").val()`

Here I use 0 when element is not defined as the default value. The  when you multiply
`item['harga_produk'] * qtyValue`